# VBA Run Time Error 424 when copying lines from one page to another (if they fulfil certain criteria)

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and coding in general, and am completely perplexed
I need to take Rows from one worksheet to another if they are populated in one column but not another but am getting Run Time Error 424: Object required. It is highlighting the starred area
Here is my code

```
Sub CopyRowsAcross()

'Name Worksheets
Dim e As Integer
Dim wsd2 As Worksheet:** Set wsd2 = Project.Sheets("DataSheet2")**
Dim wsBS As Worksheet: Set wsBS = Project.Sheets("Budget Summary")

'Set Criteria for copying lines across
For e = 2 To 1776
    'Headers
    If IsEmpty(wsd2.Cells(e, 1).Value) = False And IsEmpty(wsd2.Cells(e, 4).Value) = True Then
        wsd2.Rows(e).Copy wsBS.Rows(wsBS.Cells(wsBS.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End If
Next e

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to define `Project`, I think you meant as a `Workbook`. So use, `Dim Project As Workbook` , and then `Set Project = ThisWorkbook` , or to whatever workbook you want to set it to.

Answer (score 0):

you should assign a value to project, remove it or replace it by thisworkbook

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed it to Project when I was trying to get rid of a previous error. Life saver